# uitableview loading the cells with previous cells' content

Tags: iphone, uitableview

in my table view the cell size fits to the whole screen size. so it creating only two cells but from the 3rd cell its using old cell's content...so i am getting the incorrect data..

how to resolve this...?

thanks.

```
   - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *) tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if(cell == nil) 
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CellFrame reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    for(UIView *v in [cell.contentView subviews])
        [v removeFromSuperview];

        curCellNo = indexPath.row;
        if(curCellNo == 0){
            min = 0;
            max = 8;
            x=0;
            y=yForFirst;
            col = 1;
        }else{ 
            if(curCellNo < prevCellNo){
                min = min-12;
                max = max-12;

            }else{
                min = max;
                max = min+12;
            }
            x=0;
            y=0;
        }
        prevCellNo = curCellNo;
        NSLog(@"Max...%d",max);
        NSLog(@"Min...%d",min);
        NSLog(@"songsCount...%d",[songs count]);

        for(int i=min; i<max && i<[songs count]; i++){

            Song *thesong = [self.songs objectAtIndex:i];
            CGRect frame;
            frame.size.width=coverWidth; frame.size.height=coverHeight;
            frame.origin.x=x; frame.origin.y=y;

            LazyImageView* asyncImage = [[[LazyImageView alloc] initWithFrame:frame]autorelease];
            NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:thesong.cover];
            [asyncImage loadImageFromURL:url];

            UILabel *label = [[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, y+artistLabelYPos, artistLabelWidth, artistLabelHeight)]autorelease];
            label.text = [thesong.title stringByAppendingString:[@"\nby " stringByAppendingString:thesong.artist]];
            [label setTextAlignment:UITextAlignmentLeft];
            label.numberOfLines = 0;
            label.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:artistLabelFontSize];
            label.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
            label.backgroundColor = [UIColor darkTextColor];
            label.alpha = 0.75;

            UIButton *playBtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
            playBtn.frame = CGRectMake(x+playBtnXPos, y+playBtnYPos, playBtnWidth, playBtnHeight); 
            [playBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(playBtnClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
            if(playingButton && streamer){
                if(playingButtonTag == i && [streamer isPlaying]){
                    [playBtn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:pauseBtnimgName] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                    playingButton = playBtn;
                }else [playBtn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:playBtnimgName] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            }else [playBtn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:playBtnimgName] forState:UIControlStateNormal];


            playBtn.tag = i;
            [cell.contentView addSubview:asyncImage];
            [cell.contentView addSubview:label];
            [cell.contentView addSubview:playBtn];
            label = nil;
            asyncImage = nil;



            if(curCellNo == 0){
                y += estCoverHeight;
                if(y>=(estCoverHeight*noOfRowsInCell)){
                    col++;
                    x += estCoverWidth;
                    if(col>=3)
                        y=0;
                    else 
                        y=yForFirst;
                }   
            }else{
                col =3;
                y += estCoverHeight;
                if(y>=(estCoverHeight*noOfRowsInCell)){

                    x += estCoverWidth;
                    y=0;
                }
            }

        }

    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    cell.contentView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI/2);
    return cell; 
}
```

Comment: can you post your implementation of the `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not clearing the contents of the cell when you reuse it. This is UITableView programming 101. Please, there are WWDC videos, Stanford videos all on iTunesU that you should be watching, tableview programming guides in text if you prefer, all that touch on cell reuse.

In a nutshell: Cells are reused to save on memory. You reuse old cells when they go off screen, allocate new ones if none can be reused. If you do reuse old cells, you have to clear any subviews you placed on them first.

On a side note, you probably want a custom cell where you do the bulk of the work you're doing in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` I would strongly suggest you look into that as well.

Comment: if i remove the subviews of the cell's contentview before adding the subviews its working fine but if scroll after clicking the button on that its crashing...and its very hard to use custom cell in my situation and im editing the code in the qustion

Comment: It's never hard to use a custom cell, the only hard thing is telling yourself that it's easy to do, because it is.

Comment: actually what im doing is, had a song object with image and link for audio. so i have few songs. in table view i am displaying all the images and button on each image. in each cell im displaying 12 images but in the first cell only 9. the first image in the first cell is double in size of other images. so if i use the custom cell,  all cells should have the same frame for content... this is the problem...other wise i can easily change the content of the cell with the same frame right?

Comment: You can change the height of individual cells by section and/or row in your `tableView:heightForRowAIndexPath:` delegate method, if you need to make one larger than the rest. Also, cells don't know their size, they ask for a size based on their position in the tableview, using the aforementioned delegate method.

Answer (score 2):

It's because you are never setting the contents of the re-used UITableViewCell's

You are only providing the conetent when (cell == nil) and a new cell is allocated

Answer (score 1):

I have made this some mistake - once you make it and fix it once, you never forget :)

Instances of UITableViewCell are cached for performance reasons. The UITableView class handles this all for you. It basically caches enough instances to cover a full screen's worth of cells plus a few. That means that a table with 100 rows will run off of the same number of instances as a table with 1000 rows.

That means it is your responsibility to update the contents as they appear.

(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *) tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath is called when a cell is requested. In your implementation:

```
if(cell == nil) {
    // Instantiate the UITableViewCell here
    // Perform operations that need to occur on every cell, regardless of content
} 

// Out here, perform content assignments
```

Hopefully that clears a few things up. You basically just need to shift most of the code that is inside of the conditional to outside of the conditional. That said, I'm not condoning your use of code. You really should be implementing a custom cell. It is easier than what you are doing :)

Comment: i have different frame for the contents of first cell that is the problem. if frame of all cells' content is same i can do content assignment

Answer (score 0):

just try this

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:nil];
```

It worked for me.I had a UITableView with composed cells.I also faced the same problems.